# Bypass MVC validation for get request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register(UserRegistrationModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

The reason I do like this is because the Register page can be pre-populated with values from querystring that are generated from other pages.

The problem is that when my view gets rendered, it shows the validation errors... Is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when running an action such as this you would tend to use individual parameters rather than a complete model; what it looks like is happening is the model binder is kicking in and validating your model for you.

Can you verify by debugging the action that `ModelState.IsValid` is false and that it has some keys in it relating to the fields on your model which are invalid? If so you could try to do a `ModelState.Clear()` before you return the view to prevent the validation errors from showing up in this case.

Answer (score 4):

**Quick Answer:** try using [ValidateInput(false)] on your 'GET' action methods

**UPDATE:**
With asp.net 4, to get the framework to acknowledge the ValidateInput attribute, you'll need to configure the validation mode in the web.config as well.

Set the following as a child of the `<system.web>` element:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

**Why have a ViewModel in your 'GET' action methods?**

To take advantage of the default model binder.

For example, we have Child Actions returning partial views that are bound to complex ViewModels setup and we don't want to explicitly instantiate and rebuild the ViewModel for each Child Action.

e.g The Edit page for a an Order page takes a an EditOrderViewModel which inherits the BaseUserViewModel which in turn contains user specific display data (username, cart item count, etc.).

So the action method to return the Edit view looks like:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Edit(EditOrderViewModel editOrderVm) 
{ 
    ... 
    return View('Edit', editOrderVm );
}
```

Now as long as the Request to this child action method includes the properties of BaseUserViewModel somehow (e.g. through the Cookies, Form, and QueryString properties), then the default model binder will instantiate and populate the EditOrderViewModel with all the base view model data.

However, when we first load this page, we don't want the validation messages showing up in the form that the user hasn't had a chance to edit yet...

Hence, we turn off Model validation for the 'GET' request > just make sure you validate the 'POST' request!

Comment: Adding `ValidateInput(false)` does not work here for MVC 5. Validation is still performed due to view model argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used CustomValidation attribute in model for Create action but for another action which requires saving changes to database the validation caused error. so I fixed it by removing the CustomValidation attribute and validating the model inside the Create action method only